# Getting ..> from SQLite3 database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have connect to the shell and I am trying to list the content from a database table, but all I get is "..>".

This is what I have copied from CMD.

```
SQLite version 3.8.10.2 2015-05-20 18:17:19
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
android_metadata               diet_plan_content
diet_plan                      diet_plan_content_headline
diet_plan_calorie_calculation
sqlite> select * from diet_plan_content_headline
   ...>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the `;` at the end of the SQL statement.

Dot-commands (e.g., `.tables`) do not need that, but regular SQL statements do.

Comment: Thank you! It was not so difficult.

Comment: @Solo: Note that you can leave off the `;` if you provide the SQL statement on the command line itself (e.g., `sqlite3 foo.db "SELECT * FROM thingy WHERE something=5"`).